# Why doesn't my idea work in python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-2.x, python-decorators

Here is an idea for a dict subclass that can mutate keys.  This is a simple self contained example that's just like a `dict` but is case insensitive for `str` keys.

```
from functools import wraps

def key_fix_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], str):
            args = (args[0].lower(),) + args[1:]
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class LowerDict(dict):
    pass

for method_name in '__setitem__', '__getitem__', '__delitem__', '__contains__', 'get', 'pop', 'setdefault':
    new_method = key_fix_decorator(getattr(LowerDict, method_name))
    setattr(LowerDict, method_name, new_method)
```

<sub>**dev note:** if you copy my code for your own uses, you should implement `LowerDict.__init__` to check for any key collisions - I haven't bothered to include that for the purposes of this question</sub>

On python3 it all seems to works fine:

```
>>> d = LowerDict(potato=123, spam='eggs')
>>> d['poTATo']
123
>>> d.pop('SPAm')
'eggs'
>>> d['A']
# KeyError: 'a'
```

In python2 it doesn't even import, here is the traceback:

```
  File "/tmp/thing.py", line 15, in <module>
    new_method = key_fix_decorator(getattr(LowerDict, method_name))
  File "/tmp/thing.py", line 4, in key_fix_decorator
    @wraps(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
    setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
AttributeError: 'wrapper_descriptor' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

What could be the problem?  I can't see any version-specific code except for the `str`/`basestring` thing, which is just a minor detail not a code-breaking issue.

Comment: The difference is how `update_wrapper` is implemented in both versions.https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/functools.py#l17 and  https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/functools.py#l43

Comment: This is probably related: http://bugs.python.org/issue3445

Comment: You may also be interested in PEP 455: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0455/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `functools.wraps()` version in Python 3 can handle function objects with some of the attributes it copies across missing; the one in Python 2 cannot. This is was because [issue #3445](http://bugs.python.org/issue3445) was fixed only for Python 3; the methods of `dict` are defined in C code and have no `__module__` attribute.

Omitting the `@wraps(f)` decorator makes everything work in Python 2 too:

```
>>> def key_fix_decorator(f):
...     def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         if args and isinstance(args[0], str):
...             args = (args[0].lower(),) + args[1:]
...         return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapped
... 
>>> class LowerDict(dict):
...     pass
... 
>>> for method_name in '__setitem__', '__getitem__', '__delitem__', '__contains__', 'get', 'pop', 'setdefault':
...     new_method = key_fix_decorator(getattr(LowerDict, method_name))
...     setattr(LowerDict, method_name, new_method)
... 
>>> d = LowerDict(potato=123, spam='eggs')
>>> d['poTATo']
123
>>> d.pop('SPAm')
'eggs'
>>> d['A']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapped
KeyError: 'a'
```

You can replicate *enough* of what `wraps` does manually:

```
def key_fix_decorator(f):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], str):
            args = (args[0].lower(),) + args[1:]
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.__name__ = f.__name__
    wrapped.__doc__ = f.__doc__
    return wrapped
```

or limit the attributes that `wraps` tries to copy across:

```
def key_fix_decorator(f):
    @wraps(f, assigned=('__name__', '__doc__'))
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if args and isinstance(args[0], str):
            args = (args[0].lower(),) + args[1:]
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

You don't really need to update `__module__` attribute here; that is mostly useful only for introspection.